# Is there a way to reset my app version in Itunes Connect

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store, app-store-connect, application-loader

It's a stupid error. We mix up the build number and version string in xcode(Like build number is 1.0.1,version string is 1001). And we have distribute our app in AppStore. Now we want to correct it up. But we cannot upload it because the version must be higher than previously uploaded version. Any suggestions will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: No, you can't reset the version in iTunesConnect

Comment: If the app is not yet on the App Store, you can remove it.

Comment: Wait until you are going to send another update :|